# How to read a .csv file with C# Excel-DNA

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I would like to read a .csv file using a visual-dna Excel addin (It needs C# built function treatment before the result is displayed ). Anyone knows how to update this code so I can get an excel array as an output (In Excel of course)?

The below code is not recognised by Excel as an array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using System.IO;

namespace MyExcelDNALibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {      
        [ExcelFunction(Name = "readcsv")]

        public static object[] loadCsvFile(string filePath)
        {
           return File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(line => line != "").Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it show up if you invoke this from within excel? And, do you invoke it using <kbd>Enter</kbd> or kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are returning an array of arrays of strings. This type is not supported by Excel-DNA. Change the method return type to a 2D `object[,]` array.

Comment: Error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[][]' to 'object[*,*]'

Comment: Yes - you'll have to build the object[,] array from scratch.